# How to close one Expansion Panel when the other is opened(Angular Mat)?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to close one **expansion panel** when the other is opened. I know that by default it's set to **multi="false"** and it works absolutely fine with multiple expansion panel used inside one **accordion** but I'm only using **one panel** and I couldn't find a way to make it work. I'm still a newbie.

[Image on this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKPen.png)

**HTML Code:**

```
<mat-accordion>
      <mat-expansion-panel>
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <div
        class="col text-center"
        [ngClass]="{
          'text-green': transactionDTO.txn_type == 'CREDIT',
          'text-red': transactionDTO.txn_type == 'DEBIT',
          'text-cyan': transactionDTO.txn_type == 'WITHDRAWAL'
        }"
      >
        {{ transactionDTO.txn_type }}
      </div>
      <div class="col text-center" style="font-size: 20px;">
        {{ transactionDTO.created_date | date: "dd-MMM-yyyy" }}
      </div>
      <div class="text-center col-xl">
        {{ transactionDTO.txn_status }}
      </div>
      <div class="col text-center" style="font-size: 20px;">
        <span
          [ngClass]="{
            'text-green': transactionDTO.txn_type == 'CREDIT',
            'text-red': transactionDTO.txn_type == 'DEBIT',
            'text-cyan': transactionDTO.txn_type == 'WITHDRAWAL'
          }"
          ><ng-container
            *ngIf="
              transactionDTO.txn_type == 'WITHDRAWAL' ||
                transactionDTO.txn_type == 'DEBIT';
              else credit
            "
            >-</ng-container
          ><ng-template #credit>+</ng-template
          >{{ transactionDTO.txn_amount | currency: "USD":"":"1.2-2" }}</span
        >
      </div>
      <div class="col text-center" style="font-size: 20px;">
        {{ transactionDTO.final_amount | currency: "USD":"":"1.2-2" }}
      </div>
      <div
      class="col text-center downarrow"
      [ngClass]="{ arrow: showHistory }"
      (click)="fetchHistoryDetails()"
    >
      {{
        transactionDTO.payment_method == "Wire transfer"
          ? transactionDTO.txn_id
          : transactionDTO.payment_method
      }}
    </div>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-description>
        <div
          class="row detailsRow no-gutters justofy-content-around align-items-center"
          *ngIf="showHistory"
          marketplace-transaction-history-details
          [transactionType]="transactionDTO.transactionType"
          [userType]="'BUYER'"
          [currentStatusStep]="transactionDTO.currentStatus"
        ></div>
        </mat-panel-description>
      </mat-expansion-panel>
    </mat-accordion>
```

**CSS:**

```
.mat-expansion-panel-header{
    font-family: "Lato", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #162e4d;
}
.mat-accordion .mat-expansion-panel:last-of-type{
    margin-bottom: .3rem;
    border: 1px solid #c0c8d4;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.detailsRow{
    width: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```

**Typescript:**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { TransactionHistoryDTO } from "@shared/dto/transaction-history-dto";
@Component({
  selector: "[marketplace-transaction-history-item]",
  templateUrl: "./transaction-history-item.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./transaction-history-item.component.scss"],
})
export class TransactionHistoryItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() transactionDTO:TransactionHistoryDTO;
  showHistory = true;
  constructor() {}

  fetchHistoryDetails() {
    this.showHistory = !this.showHistory;
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    // console.log(this.transactionDTO);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is confusing. If you are using only one panel, then how come there is need to close others? But from the image you linked and code you share, you can put the panels inside the accordion. Or is there something else you have to explain? The aim of the accordion is to group panels you see.

Comment: Yes, from the image you can see that two expansion panels are opened at the same time but what I am trying to figure out is to close the other one when a new one is opened

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the first comment, i just see only one expansion-panel in the code you posted. Anyway looking at the image you linked, if you have more expansion panels and you want just one to be axpanded at time, you can just go like this in the HTML:

```
<mat-expansion-panel class="" [expanded]="step === 0" (opened)="setStep(0)">
</mat-expansion-panel>

<mat-expansion-panel class="" [expanded]="step === 1" (opened)="setStep(1)">
</mat-expansion-panel>

<mat-expansion-panel class="" [expanded]="step === 2" (opened)="setStep(2)">
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

While in your .TS :

```
step :number = 0; //global variable

setStep(index:number){
    this.step = index;
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Yes I'm using one panel and it's connected to paginator. I do not have more expansion panels.

Comment: Ok, but in the image you posted i see 4 expansion panels and as you mentioned "two expansion panels are opened at the same time but what I am trying to figure out is to close the other one when a new one is opened" . I'm not sure i understood but anyway, to close other expansion panels you can use the way i posted, so that only one panel can be opened at time.

Comment: Forget about the bottom two. I just want the first one closed when second one is opened and please check my HTML how I am utilizing one panel.

Comment: You can still use the [expanded] and (opened) directives on your <mat-expansion-panel> tag. Until the panels are all on the same page you just need to add these directives along with a global variable defined in you .ts file. Whenever the panel is clicked, it will be opened and the variable set to its value, so that if there's another panel opened, it will be closed. If you want this logic to be applied only to the first two panels, add the directives just to those two expansion panels and they will work this way